# What is the proper way to test SpringBoot Database with H2?

Tags: database, unit-testing, spring-boot, h2, mybatis

I am trying to run Springboot test with H2 in-memory db with Mybatis.
So far I have done

1. configuring h2 DB in application-test.properties
2. adding annotation

```
@SpringBootTest, @TestPropertySource (locations = "TEST_APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_LOCATION")
```

3. autowiring dao and serviceImpl beans
4. adding seed.sql and purge.sql to the test class with

```
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:/database/seed.sql"),
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:/database/purge.sql") })
```

Despite the above measures, I still have two problems

1. I can't retrieve user that I input with the seed.sql. I made a user with id="admin", pw="admin", and was trying to retrieve with findById("admin"). But it always returns null.
2. I can't open h2 DB while debugging with the @test. I simply can't access h2 with localhost:8080/h2-console (the path was written explicitly in application-test.properties)

Is there any extra measure that I should take to test SpringBoot with h2?

Answer (score 0):

Add    `spring.h2.console.enabled=true`    in your properties file.

Comment: Yes I have added that to the application.properties, but still not able to enter the console.